# jQuery - Hide / Show elements related to selected radio

Tags: jquery

I want to `show` the icon and `hide` the text only on when a radio with `name='method'` is checked. The problem with this code is that when I select a different radio, the function doesn't reset the original state of the un-selected radio where the icon is hidden and the text is shown.

I can't get the `else` portion of the function to reset the radio back to it's original state (where the text is showing and icon is hidden)?

```js
$("input[name='method']").on("change", function() {
  var text = $(this).closest(".item").find(".text");
  var icon = $(this).closest(".item").find(".icon");

  icon.hide();
  text.show();

  if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
    text.hide();
    icon.show();
  } else {
    icon.hide();
    text.show();
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="item">
  <div class="icon"></div>
  <label class="text">choose?
    <input type="radio" name="method">
  </label>
</div>
<div class="item">
  <div class="icon"></div>
  <label class="text">choose?
    <input type="radio" name="method" checked>
  </label>
</div>
```

Comment: What happens if you include `console.log( this.checked );` within the event handler?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your design assumes that when the previously checked radio button is uncheched the change event fires. The truth is it does not; the change event fires only when a radio changes state from unchecked to checked. If you redesign with that in mind, you should be alright.

In the demo below, I have added:

```
console.log( this.checked );
```

To show that. So, there is no need of the if statement because for every radio button that fires the change event `this.checked` is `true` so the else part would never be executed.
Therefore, the following two lines should take care of resetting the texts and icons:

```
allTexts.not(text).show();
allIcons.not(icon).hide();
```

Also the following code has been added at the end to keep the initial state consistent:

```
.filter(':checked').change();
```

**NOTE**

- Another approach would be to show all texts and hide all icons (no need of `.not()`), then hide text and show icon of checked radio.

**DEMO**

```js
$("input[name='method']").on("change", function() {
  console.log( this.checked );
  var text = $(this).closest(".item").find(".text");
  var icon = $(this).closest(".item").find(".icon");
  var allTexts = $('.item > .text');
  var allIcons = $('.item > .icon');

  text.hide();
  icon.show();
  allTexts.not(text).show();
  allIcons.not(icon).hide();
})
.filter(':checked').change();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="item">
  <div class="icon">1</div>
  <label class="text">choose?
    <input type="radio" name="method">
  </label>
</div>
<div class="item">
  <div class="icon">2</div>
  <label class="text">choose?
    <input type="radio" name="method" checked>
  </label>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing this might be a student project so I don't want to change the way you have chosen to do this, so I'll help you fix up the problem you mention. Below I'll go step-by-step through the reasons for the problems you have, and what you can do to overcome them.

**1.** The reason nothing happens when you click on a radio button that doesn't have `name='method'` because your handler is triggered *only* by clicks on inputs with that name:

```
$("input[name='method']").on("change", function() {
```

**2.** To run your function on all input clicks, you need to add the handler to all inputs, check the input name and then show or hide the radio buttons (note I've added a container for your inputs called `radiocontainer`, so we don't inadvertently select other inputs on your page):

```
$(".radiocontainer  input").on("change", function() {
  if ($(this).attr('name') == "method") {
      //show icon and hide text
  }
  else{
      //hide icons and show text for "method" inputs
  }
}
```

**3.** Now, the clicks still only apply to the `closest` text and icon. This is find for a "method" input, but if the click is not on a "method" inputs, you need to reset the text & icons for *all* "method" inputs. You can do that like this:

```
// get all the inputs with name="method"
$("input[name='method']").each(function(i) {
    $inputparent = $(this).parent(".text"); // get the input's parent with the "text" class...
    $inputparent.show();  //... and show it
    $inputparent.prev(".icon").hide(); // now get the previous sibling to the "text" with the icon class and hide it:
});
```

**Note**: if you can change the HTML it would make it easier to manage this, e.g. add an extra class on the `item` divs to make it easier to change the text and icon elements associated with the "method" inputs. When designing your HTML, also think about how you need to access them in your code.

**Working Example** putting all this together:

```js
/* function to find all "method" inputs and reset them */
function resetIconsText() {
  $(".radiocontainer input[name='method']").each(function(i) {
    $(this).parent(".text").show();
    $(this).parent(".text").prev(".icon").hide();
  });
}
// set up the default state for the method inputs
resetIconsText();

$(".radiocontainer input").on("click", function() {

  var text = $(this).closest(".item").find(".text");
  var icon = $(this).closest(".item").find(".icon");

  if ($(this).attr('name') == "method") {
    if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
      text.hide();
      icon.show();
    } else {
      icon.hide();
      text.show();
    }
  } else {
    resetIconsText();
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="radiocontainer">
  <div class="item">
    <div class="icon"></div>
    <label class="text">choose?
    <input type="radio" name="method">
  </label>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <div class="icon"></div>
    <label class="text">choose?
    <input type="radio" name="method" checked>
  </label>
  </div>

  <div class="item">
    <div class="icon"></div>
    <label class="text">Not method - reset method icons and text
    <input type="radio" name="notmethod">
  </label>
  </div>
</div>
```